# FMU Export from Dymola of model with medium from ExternalMedia

Tags: media, modelica, dymola, fmi

I'm trying to export a test model of the ***ExternalMedia* library to FMU**.
When converting the model to FMU I get errors, with both, Visual Studio 2010 and MinGW GCC compilers.
The model simulates well in Dymola with VisualStudio, but the export as FMU fails.

I usually **start-up Dymola with a mos-Script**, setting the working directory, adding a Modelica path and importing the used libraries.
The mos-script looks like this:

```
cd("D:\Projekte\xxx\Modelica");

AddModelicaPath("D:\Projekte\xxx\Modelica\Library", erase=false);

import ExternalMedia.*;

openModel("D:\Projekte\xxx\Modelica\MyModel.mo");
```

When looking for the environment variable **MODELICAPATH**, I cannot find it. It’s  not defined on my machine.
Why? Installation issue?
And could this be the problem?

The test model from the ***ExternalMedia*** library

***github.com/modelica/ExternalMedia***

can be found at ***ExternalMedia.Test.TestMedium.TestConstants***

Attached you can find the **output error messages** of dymola (buildlog.txt) for the two cases:

**Case 1:** Windows7, Dymola 2016, VisualStudio 2010 Express -> simulation OK!

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2au1say0td20q1/buildlog_VisualStudio2010Express_Compiler.txt?dl=0

][1]

**Case 2:** Windows 7, Dymola 2016, MinGW GCC -> Error during translation, no simulation possible

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/tu640zm1ydtmuls/buildlog_MinGW_GCC_Compiler.txt?dl=0][2]

Where do the errors come from?
ExternalMedia, Dymola, FMI settings, or is it due to system settings (windows environment variables etc.)?

Comment: I think the AddModelicaPath() function only works temporarily within the current Dymola process, it won't add anything to the Environment variable. I am not really sure how it happened with the compiler, it might relate to some settings for the static lib in ExternalMedia and Dymola FMU export are different, but I am not really sure how to resolve this. You could probably try to export the source code and compile it offline.